# Who can pick up a passport with stamped visa?

Tags: usa, passports, regulations, indian-citizens, b1-b2-visas

I live in the USA. My parents live in India. We have applied for B2 visas to the USA for my parents to come and visit me. The only passport collection option shown when booking the interview was to pick up from the consulate. The US Consulate is a bit far from the town where my parents.

Hence my question:

- Who can pick up the Passport with stamped visa. Does it have to be my parents, or could they nominate someone to pick them up?

Comment: What is the country you are living in? I would surprised if someone else could pick-up their passports though

Answer (score 6):

Following the links for visa application from the website of any U.S. consulate in India takes you to USTravelDocs.com, which appears to be the contractor handling the processing. I would thus take this site to be authoritative, and yes, your parents can appoint someone else to pick up their passports for them.

The [Passport/Visa Collection Locations and Timings](http://www.ustraveldocs.com/in/in-loc-passportcollection.asp) page provides a table of the documents required to pick up a passport; of interest to you is the second column under “Pick-up Information”:

> Representative collecting passport — even in case of family members:
>
> 1. A photocopy of applicant's government-issued photo ID
> 2. Representative's original government-issued photo ID and 1 photocopy;
> 3. Original authorization letter

In other words, if they were to ask a friend to pick up their passports for them, the friend would need to carry

- the friend's own ID and photocopy of the friend's ID
- a photocopy of each parent's ID
- a letter signed by each of the parents naming the the friend and authorizing him or her to accept the passports on their behalf. It does not specify a language, but it would not hurt to have a version in English.

Additionally, it looks like the passports need not be collected at the consulate or embassy itself. Under “Locations and Timings” there a link showing 28 additional locations which Stanley and Blue Dart will deliver to, although it seems you must have specified the delivery location in the original application.

Comment: I think you have mis-read the requirements. You've said they would require "each parent's original ID", however the quoted list does not say this.

Comment: Your quoted text says "A **photocopy** of applicant's government-issued photo ID", but you then state they will require the **originals** and a photocopy.  The table on the website you link to specifically shows that the applicants original id is NOT required when the passport is being picked up by someone else.

Comment: @Doc Ah, you're right. Post edited.